# ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES when proxying through https localhost to another https domain

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ssl, https, proxy

I run a local HTTPS server that uses *fake certificates*, (same as [`webpack-dev-server`'s approach](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/utils/getCertificate.js) for https), and uses [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) to proxy to another domain.

~10% of the requests randomly drop with `ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES` error. Looks like the requests drop on the browser side - they don't seem to reach the server at all.

This happens only on Chrome and a specific domain, but doesn't happen in other browsers or on other domains (even `https://www.google.com`).

I saw reports of `ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES` related to LastPass, so I created a new profile for Chrome to ensure no extensions are running, and the issue still occurs.

I'm trying to understand where the root cause is. Is it the proxy/ssl handshake/server config?

```js
const { createServer } = require("https");
const fakeHttpsCert = require("fake-https-cert");

const httpProxy = require("http-proxy");

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: "https://example.com",
  changeOrigin: true,
  secure: false,
});

const fakeCert = fakeHttpsCert(console);
const ssl = { key: fakeCert, cert: fakeCert, requestCert: false };

createServer(ssl, (req, res) => {
  proxy.web(req, res);
}).listen(4001);
```

[image: Dropped requests in Console]